# How to know which device is causing PCIe Bus Error severity=Corrected AER: Corrected error received

Tags: drivers, grub2, 22.04, pcie, elementary

I've begun noticing the /dev/mapper/data-root volume was 100% used
Then noticed logs kern.log and syslog were 95gb each

```
Aug 1 08:24:42 mypc kernel: [73212.049797] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Aug 1 08:24:42 mypc kernel: [73212.049802] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 1 08:24:42 mypc kernel: [73212.049803] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a294] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 1 08:24:42 mypc kernel: [73212.049804] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 1 08:24:42 mypc kernel: [73212.050514] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
Aug 1 08:24:42 mypc kernel: [73212.050519] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 1 08:24:42 mypc kernel: [73212.050520] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a294] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 1 08:24:42 mypc kernel: [73212.050522] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] RxErr
```

Then remembered about pci=noaer in the grub file
I've done that and seems to be solved, but

**Is there any way to know which is de "faulty" device and why is causing that?**
And finally, how to solve that error and solve the log filling without editing the grub file?

Here is my
**lspci -nn**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:3ec2] (rev 0d)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] [8086:3e98] (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a2af]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1 [8086:a2ba]
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a282]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:a294] (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 [8086:a297] (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #11 [8086:a29a] (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a2ca]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller [8086:a2a1]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio [8086:a2f0]
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:a2a3]
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:818b]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is whatever is in this port `00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:a294] (rev f0)` that is failing.  I would recommend removing hardware from the PCI ports and testing.  It could be also a built in GPU error, or a motherboard error.  Either would need to be replaced if you are still getting the error after stripping down the motherboard of added hardware.  There really isn't a lot of info out there about this device:  https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-a294-1462-7a90